# How to update duplicate records in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We are allowing duplicate records in the database with the exception of id. When a record is updated, we want to find and update any duplicates. Through research I have found Hibernate's event method beforeUpdate and afterUpdate. The problem is that when I find duplicates and start iterating through them, I get this error:

ERROR:Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Here is my afterUpdate code in the Domain:

```
1      def afterUpdate() {
2          println "\n*** afterUpdate ***"
3          def record = this
4
5          DomainObject.createCriteria().list() {
6              ne( 'id', record.id )
7              or {
8                  eq( 'storeId', record.storeId )
9                  and {
10                     eq( 'firstName', record.firstName )
11                     eq( 'lastName', record.lastName )
12                     eq( 'dateOfBirth', record.dateOfBirth )
13                 }
14             }
15             //eq( 'lastUpdated', record.lastUpdated )
16         }.each { dupe ->
17             log.info "syncing ${dupe.id} with ${record.id}"
18             dupe.properties.each{ key, value ->
19                 println "*** prop: ${key}: ${value}"
20             }
21         }
22     }
23
```

The error is on line 19. We are using Grails 2.4.4 and developing on Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping). Pay attention to this section about the use of `withNewSession`:

```
class Person {
   String name
   def beforeDelete() {
      ActivityTrace.withNewSession {
         new ActivityTrace(eventName: "Person Deleted", data: name).save()
      }
   }
}
```

> Notice the usage of withNewSession method above. Since events are
>   triggered whilst Hibernate is flushing using persistence methods like
>   save() and delete() won't result in objects being saved unless you run
>   your operations with a new Session.
>
> Fortunately the withNewSession method lets you share the same
>   transactional JDBC connection even though you're using a different
>   underlying Session.

Comment: Crap, I must have missed the .withNewSession part! Thank you Joshua!